# Type Error: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to run this simple piece of code, basically it changes the label and icon based on the status (string)

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="container.length > 0">
                <span *ngIf="!container.status.includes('Paused') && container.status.includes('Up')"
                      class="label label-success label-lg-status"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> Completed - {{ container.status }}</span>
                <span *ngIf="container.status.includes('Paused')" class="label label-warning label-lg-status"><span
                  class="fa fa-pause"></span> Completed - {{ container.status }}</span>
                <span *ngIf="container.status.includes('Exited')" class="label label-danger label-lg-status"><span
                  class="fa fa-stop"></span> Completed - {{ container.status }}</span>
   </ng-container>
```

but i was getting an error saying cannot use includes of null so I put `*ngIf="container.length > 0"` and now I get `ReportComponent.html:22 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

How can I make the html wait for the execution of the get requests?

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

  private containerName:string;
  private processes = [];
  private container = [];
  private settings = [];
  private environment = [];
  private id:Number;

  constructor(private _route:ActivatedRoute, private dockerService:DockerService, private environmentService:EnvironmentService, private settingsService:SettingsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      // Get Environment id
      this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        // Get Environment
        this.environmentService.getEnvironment(this.id).subscribe( environment => {
          this.environment = environment;
          console.log(environment);
          //this.containerName = this.environment.name;
        });
        // Get Docker processes
        this.dockerService.getProcesses(this.containerName).subscribe(processes => {
          this.processes = processes;
        });
        // Get Docker Container Object
        this.dockerService.getContainer(this.containerName).subscribe( container => {
          this.container = container;
        });
        // Get Settings
        this.settingsService.getSettings().subscribe( settings => {
          this.settings = settings;
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Let us know the console output of `container`

Comment: Try *ngIf="container?.length > 0"

Comment: Question title does't match description..Change title as per description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes can use it like this, it will be more Angular way

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="container?.length > 0">
```

It will work too.

Comment: explain please.

Comment: `?` will add an optional parameter. i.e. `length` might exist or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like :

```
*ngIf="container && (container.length > 0)"
```

Error will be removed.

It won't check `length` unless `container` array is available.

Answer (score 0):

> Your exact problem is the service call is asynchronous. So  DOM rendering is started before the value is binding in the `container` object. Because DOM rendering does not wait for the completion of your asynchronous service response

The solution is, you should initialize your array inside of nginit.

Try this

```
 ngOnInit() {
       this.container = []//add this
      // Get Environment id
      this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['id'];
        // Get Environment
        this.environmentService.getEnvironment(this.id).subscribe( environment => {
          this.environment = environment;
          console.log(environment);
          //this.containerName = this.environment.name;
        });
        // Get Docker processes
        this.dockerService.getProcesses(this.containerName).subscribe(processes => {
          this.processes = processes;
        });
        // Get Docker Container Object
        this.dockerService.getContainer(this.containerName).subscribe( container => {
          this.container = container;
        });
        // Get Settings
        this.settingsService.getSettings().subscribe( settings => {
          this.settings = settings;
        });
    });
  }
}
```